# OSX Apache Virtualhost returns only default page

Tags: macos, apache-http-server

I have a problem using the build-in apache webserver under ElCapitan.

I want to set up my Sites-Directory in my users-directory. This works fine by adding a user config and and so on. So my localhost/~Fabian gives me the content of /User/Fabian/Sites/index.php.

Now I am trying to set up virtual hosts in this directory, e.g. /User/Fabian/Sites/Projekte/testsite.me/public.

So I activated the virtualhost module and included it in my httpd.conf. After this, I set up a virtualhost in the httpd-vhost.conf:

```
</VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin xyz@blubber.de
    DocumentRoot "/Users/Fabian/Sites/Projekte/testsite.me/public"
    ServerName testsite.me
    ErrorLog "/Users/Fabian/Sites/Logs/testsite-error_log"
    CustomLog "/Users/Fabian/Sites/Logs/testsite-custom_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I also added the ServerAlias to my hosts file

127.0.0.1    testsite.me

Trying to open http://testsite.me shows me the default "It works"-page.

Running apachectl configtest gives me an syntax error:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 499 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 74 of /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf: </VirtualHost without matching <VirtualHost section
```

Line 499 in httpd.conf looks like this:

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Line 74ff of httpd-vhosts.conf contain the virtualhost I defined above.

Any idea how to solve this problem? What is a VirtualHost section?

Thank you!